# Polygon covering footprints

Tags: footprint, polygon

I am new at designing, when I pouring copper in the polygon, it covers the footpring:
[image]

BTW, there is any option to edit footprint from the web?
At the picture above there isnt "Top overlay" around the components.

Comment: You should have started stating which tool you are using.

Comment: Your CAD program should have a footprint editor where you can modify existing footprints, or make new ones.

Answer (score 2):

That's working as intended.  If you don't want it to touch the pads, you'll have to set "Don't Pour Over Same Net Objects" or "Pour Over Same Net Polygons Only" from the Polygon Manager window.  If you want thermal vias, you'll have to select "Relief Connect" under "SMD Pad Connection" in the rule editor under Plane > Polygon Connect Style > PolygonConnect.